# ExtendedFloatingActionButton not respondig to RecyclerView scroll and not executing onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, floating-action-button

the situation is as follows.

> Quick recap, the ExtendedFloatingActionButton is not reacting to the
> RecyclerView addOnScrollListener but the regular button is working just fine.

**Detailed explanation with code:**

I have a main activity that is split into two. On the left side is fragment1 and on the right side is fragment2. In fragment one, I have some data that populates recyclerView and ExtendedFloatingActionButton in the corner. On scroll, I want to hide/show the button (or shrink/extend it), and on button click I want to start some background logic. **The problem is that the FAB is not reacting on scroll and something weird is going on when I click it ripple effect is activated, so the click is registered but the onClick function is not called. The funny thing is that when I put the regular button instead of FAB everything works as intended.**

I have been stuck debugging this for more than a day now, but I just can't seem to find what the problem is.

I have a MainActivity that is split into two fragments (tablet app).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<include
    android:id="@+id/frag1"
    layout="@layout/frag_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/frag2"
    layout="@layout/frag_two"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code for the MainActivity

```
    Frag1 frag1= new Frag1();
    Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag1, frag1);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag2, frag2 );

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Java code for Fragment1

```
     extendedFloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
     //helper class that ads addOnScrollListener on RecyclerView
     helperClass.scrollHelper(recyclerView, extendedFloatingActionButton);
     extendedFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

XML code for Fragment1

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorBackground"
   tools:context=".fragments.Frag1">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryButton"
    android:text="ADD"
    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryButton"
    app:icon="@drawable/icon_ok"
    app:iconTint="@color/colorSecondaryButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'll also include all the dependencies that i use just in case

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

//material design
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'

//scalable size unit (support for different screen size)
implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6"
implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6"

//room database
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0"

//preferences
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0"

//jetpack navigation component ....
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2"
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.4.2'

//livedata
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.2'

//recycler view decoration on swipe
implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.4'

//Gson dependency
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

//barcode scanner
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'

// volley http library
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

//facebook shimmer
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0@aar'
```

Scroll helper

```
public void scrollHelper(RecyclerView layoutView, ExtendedFloatingActionButton button) {
    layoutView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                // Scrolling down - visibility or shrkink
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                // Scrolling up
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm open to implementing any suggestions you might have. Ignore my naming in the example above, since it's just an example.

Cheers.

Comment: What's the logic inside helperClass? It seems you are sending the recyclerview and the fab to it.

Comment: @tomerpacific updated the question with the code. just a simple call to addOnScrollListener and passing variables. But since I use it in multiple parts of the app this is more manageable to maintain.